# How can I run a macro in an Excel file I open with Perl?

Tags: perl, vba, excel

How can I run a macro in an Excel file I open with Perl?

Comment: Do you have Excel installed, or are you looking for a pure Perl solution?

Comment: Which platform are you using? Most likely you are going to have to open it through Excel then tell Excel what to do. That might be easy through Win32::OLE.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a skeleton of what might work.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::OLE;

my $excel= Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application') 
    or die "Could not create Excel.Application!\n"
    ;
$excel->Workbooks->open( 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\Book1.xlsx' );
$excel->run( 'Book1!Macro1' );
$excel->quit;
```

One of the most sure ways that you can do this is to simply record a macro of opening a spreadsheet and running a macro. And then taking a look at the macro code that was generated and convert it into Perl. Keep in mind that the OLE object is the Application object.

9/22/2010 - I added `quit` to stop Excel from running.

Comment: excel.exe not hang after the perl script. In taskmgr many duplicate excel.exe. How can I fix it?

Comment: `undef $excel;` at the end will stop excel.exe

Comment: @Powertieke & @jushlwest: I added `$excel->quit()` to stop the process from running.