# How can I complete the process in Win32 on behalf of the process in Perl?

Tags: windows, perl, winapi, kill, taskmanager

For example, to have rschit process excell.exe means Perl.

Comment: Can you please provide more details? I have no clue what you're talking about.

Comment: Looking at his other questions, i'm guessing he wants to kill an app/process in win32 (excel in particular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is about the process remaining around in "server mode" after automation, you can just call the `quit` method on the application object. I edited by answer at [How can I run a macro in an Excel file I open with Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751403/how-can-i-run-a-macro-in-an-excel-file-i-open-with-perl/3751790#answer-3751790) to include that. (You know, I thought if I told you that it was an `Application` object, you could read the [MS documentation on that object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213696%28office.11%29.aspx) to figure out what you wanted to do. )

---

However, you can kill a process in windows with `taskkill.exe`. You can read up by typing `taskkill /?` on the command line. It will handle `taskkill /IM excel.exe`.

But if you want a specific PID, you need to use `tasklist.exe`. (Type `tasklist` at the command prompt to see the output. Or `tasklist /?` for more information.)

The code below uses both:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use English qw<$OS_ERROR>;
use File::Spec;

my $sys32dir = File::Spec->catfile( $ENV{SYSTEMROOT}, 'System32' );
my $tasklist_exe = File::Spec->catfile( $sys32dir, 'tasklist.exe' );
my ( $excel_line ) = grep { /^excel.exe\b/i } `$tasklist_exe`;
# $excel_line: 'EXCEL.EXE  4468 Console  1  20,968 K

# The PID is the second column
my ( undef, $pid ) = split qr{\s+}, $excel_line;

if ( my $rc = system( File::Spec->catfile( $sys32dir, 'taskkill.exe' )
   , '/PID', $pid 
   )) {
    die ( $OS_ERROR + 0 ) . ' - ' . $OS_ERROR;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to fire a system call to "taskkill /IM excel.exe" ?